# How to you suppress the "cross-site cookie" warnings in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cookies, devtools

The project I'm working on has tons of warnings like this:

```
Cookie “<xxx>” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “<yyy>” because the scheme does not match.
```

These cookies are set by third-party scripts I don't have control over.  The warnings do appear in the devtools console, though, masking the more important output.  How can I suppress this type of warning, so they don't show at all?

Firefox 91 on Macos Catalina.